# jQuery 1.9.0 - jQuery UI DatePicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Создаю форму с кучей форм ввода даты datepickerов (вызов датепискеров *onclick*)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Событие на нажатие:

```
onclick="Configurator.attactDateConstraints(this)"
```

Вызов конфигуратора

```
attactDateConstraints: function (elems)
    {
        $(elems).datepicker().attr('maxlength', 19);
    }
```

Проблема в том, что в первый раз datapicker не появляется.

НО!, если нажать на первый, потом на другой, а потом снова на первый - появится.

Comment: Версия jQueryUI - 1.10.0

Comment: Надо создать datepicker после загрузки документа\построения html, а не во время клика.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko но их слишком много (больше сотни)

Comment: Ничего особо страшного в этом нет. А если боитесь за производительность, то можете замерить, сколько времени это займет.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko спасибо